# How do I temporarily disable warnings for usage of [[deprecated]] variables?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm using C++'s `[[deprecated]]` attribute on a variable. There's some implementation code that still uses this variable for backward compatibility support. I do not want that code to issue a compiler warning. However, I do want to issue warnings if people introduce *new* code that uses that deprecated variable.

Is there a compiler-agnostic way to disable warnings for usage of `[[deprecated]]` variables? If not, do I have to do this (in the example of MSVC):

```cpp
struct MyObject
{
    int foo;

    [[deprecated("Use foo instead")]]
    int bar;

    void do_setup()
    {
        foo = 1;

        // For backward compatibility only
        #pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
        bar = 2;
    }
};
```

The part I don't like about this solution is that it depends on non-standard, toolchain-defined `pragma` directives. There's also probably some `#ifdef` hell that I'll get into, since I also support Clang.

Using C++17, what is the most recommended method of suppressing toolchain warnings/diagnostics for usage of entities marked `[[deprecated]]`? For context: This is important because I treat warnings as errors on all toolchains I build with.

Comment: I don't see any standard way to ignore warnings.

Comment: @Jarod42 `suppress` does this automatically for the next line only.

Comment: The standard doesn't even require a diagnostic message be surfaced in the first place so it does not have a way to stop it.  You are in implementation defined behavior land and you'll need to decide which implementations you want to cover.

Comment: I don't think "deprecated" is a good tool for "backwards compatibility feature". A thing is deprecated because there is an intent to remove it. Backwards compatibility features are *features* and thus users should expect support for it. I understand the desire to want to prevent new code from using certain things, but think about it: what would prevent new code from simply using whatever deprecated bypass would be provided? Either users should stop using it or they should expect it to be supported; there's no middle-ground here.

Comment: @NicolBolas Backward compatibility in this case is for interoperability with older versions of another component of software. I deprecate them because eventually the intent is the code will be removed. It is not guaranteed to remain there. It also communicates that I do not want that code touched/improved. Don't waste your time with it, basically. Once all older versions are gone, the code can be safely removed. There is definitely a middle ground. I don't think that "backward compatibility" is defined in such a strict way as you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standards-driven way of disabling warnings for using a deprecated name from a particular block of code, because the standard itself only suggests how implementations might want to react to `deprecated`, and that suggestion is just "warn if the program refers to the name".

An easy alternative approach is to rename the original name, and have a deprecated shim refer to it:

```cpp
struct MyObject
{
    int foo;

    int bar_; // renamed from bar

    [[deprecated("Use foo instead")]]
    int& bar = bar_;

    void do_setup()
    {
        foo = 1;

        // For backward compatibility only
        bar_ = 2;
    }
};
```

That's a much better fit for deprecated *functions*, of course, since shimming a function is basically free. Here you're taking up space for the reference in each `MyObject`, and you'll need to be very careful with your copy/move/assignment stuff. (And note that a `const MyObject` will still have a non-const `bar`.) Alternatively, you could make `bar_` into a member function returning a reference to `bar` (and also a const version of that), for a similar effect.

If you wanted to mark a free function/global variable as deprecated, you've got more flexibility, since the `deprecated` attribute can be on a *re*declaration. Check it:

```
int deprecatedFunc()
{
    return 3;
}

int grandfathered()
{
    return deprecatedFunc();
}

[[deprecated("NO")]]
int deprecatedFunc();

int warnme()
{
    return deprecatedFunc();
}
```

So you could have an "internal" header without `deprecated`, and have a user-facing header which includes the internal header and then redeclares with `deprecated`. Tragically, you can't go the other way: Once a name is declared as `deprecated` once, you can't un-deprecate it with a later redeclaration.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide it from the compiler:

```
struct MyObject
{
    int foo;

    [[deprecated("Use foo instead")]]
    int bar;

    void do_setup()
    {
        foo = 1;

        // Fooled you compiler!
        _bar() = 2;
    }

private:
    auto _bar() noexcept -> int&;
    auto _bar() const noexcept -> int const&;
};
```

Then, in another file:

```
auto MyObject::_bar() noexcept -> int& {
    return bar;
}

auto MyObject::_bar() const noexcept -> int const& {
    return bar;
}
```

Then, you can compile this file with all warning disabled. In GCC and Clang, it's done with `-Wno-deprecated-declarations`